# Add events in full-calendar with Ionic 2

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app, wich is using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

I followed these [steps](https://gist.github.com/netcell/d98d149394fdd11e3134fbd4514a5c55) to use it on Ionic 2 and it works very well.

But now, I need to create events dinamically from the page component that include this custom component.

I have an profile component:
- in `profile.ts`, I'm retriving dates per user from firebase.
- in `profile.html`, I have this selector: `<full-calendar></full-calendar>`

So, in profile page, I can see the calendar, and I've already edited their styles. Now I want to create events from this page, but I don't know how to reference it properly.

I tried with:

```
import { FullCalendarComponent } from .....

@Component({
....
    providers: [FullCalendarComponent]
})

.
.
.
FullCalendarComponent.calendarOptions.events = myEvents;
```

But I can't see any change running it, and console don't throws me any errors..

Thank's so much in advance!

**EDIT**:

In full calendar component (components/full-calendar):

**full-calendar.html**:

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

**full-calendar.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'full-calendar',
    templateUrl: 'full-calendar.html'
})
export class FullCalendarComponent {

    calendarOptions: any = {  // Before it was type : Object
        //height: 'parent',
        locale: 'es',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        fixedWeekCount : false,
        weekends: true,/**
        defaultDate: '2017-01-03',*/
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        defaultView: 'month', //basicWeek
        allDaySlot: false,
        minTime: '06:00:00',
        maxTime: '23:00:00',
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title', //'prev, title, next'
            right: 'next'
        },
        events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2016-09-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2016-09-07',
            end: '2016-09-10'
        }]
    }
}
```

In profile page component (pages/profile):

**profile.html**: (I have more code but only show the important)

```
<div class="calendar">
    <full-calendar [options]="calOptions" #mycal></full-calendar>
</div>
```

**profile.ts**:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '../../components/full-calendar/full-calendar';
import * as $ from 'jquery';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    providers: [FullCalendarComponent]
})
export class ProfilePage {
@ViewChild('mycal', { read: ElementRef }) myCal: ElementRef;

calOptions: any = {
    locale: 'es',
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    fixedWeekCount : false,
    weekends: true,/**
    defaultDate: '2017-01-03',*/
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    defaultView: 'month', //basicWeek
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: '06:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00:00',
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title', //'prev, title, next'
        right: 'next'
    },
    events: []
};

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public platform: Platform,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public auth: FirebaseAuth
) {}

public setCalendarEvents(): void {

    let events: Array<any> = [];

    for (let entry of this.consecutiveDates) {
        let event = {
            allDay: true,
            title: ' ',
            start: entry
        };

        events.push(event);
    }

    this.calOptions.events = events;
    $(this.myCal.nativeElement).fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
}
```

This throws me:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'full-calendar'.
1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that there are no errors? I wonder. you can instead use the official ionic components ?

Comment: Wait i am little confused, He is able to display cal but not events?

Comment: @Smit  Sorry, I forget to mention that I can see the events that are declared as examples in calendarOptions, within the full-calendar component that I created:
Events: [
       {
         Title: 'All Day Event',
         Start: '2016-09-01'
       },
       {
         Title: 'Long Event',
         Start: '2016-09-07',
         End: '2016-09-10'
       }
     ]

But if I do FullCalendarComponent.calendarOptions.events = events, no effect appears.

Comment: Now I'm trying to reference fullcalendar with: $("full-calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', {title:' ', start:'2017-03-06'});   but it's not working. Maybe I'm not properly referencing it..

Comment: @IvanLencina I have added answer, you can review it. There are some revisions to be made.

Comment: Hey. Could you help for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718363/how-to-properly-integrate-fullcalendar-in-ionic-2) ?

Answer (score 2):

The .ts doesnt work sometime. Some suggested to create you own.

But here is what i have done. In the .ts create a elementRef. Class variables

```
@ViewChild('mycal', { read: ElementRef }) myCal: ElementRef
calOptions: any = {}; //options
```

And then when you have events say, from `firebase`, do the below. where `slots` are your `events`. In some method.

```
this.calOptions.events = slots
 $(this.myCal.nativeElement).fullCalendar('addEventSource', slots)
```

Remember: `slots` is array of objects not a single object!

In html:

```
<full-calendar [options]="calOptions "#mycal></full-calendar>
```

More information: https://gist.github.com/shah-smit/85aff341cd4a20494910ab2c17e82777/edit

Comment: @ViewChild() ... Should it go in my profile.ts or in my full-calendar.ts? Anyway, I'm throwing this error:  Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'full-calendar'.
1. If 'full-calendar' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-calendar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: The above code should be in profle.ts! You should import fullcalendar as you are doing so.

Comment: options is a input for the full calendar, if `fullcalendar` isnt a known property than u must resolve that issue first.

Comment: Yes, i'm doing it. I will share my code in the post and I will tell you to see it

Comment: Oh. Now I releasie that `full-calendar` is ur defined selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137382/discussion-between-smit-and-ivan-lencina).

Comment: @IvanLencina I have added the answer into the chat and added link to the answer. Please refer and let me know if that solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello. How about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718363/how-to-properly-integrate-fullcalendar-in-ionic-2) ? Can you help there ?